# Setting minimum value of a argument in a PHP function

Tags: php

Alright so what I am trying to achieve is quite simple but I haven't yet found a way to do it.

I am basically trying to set the "minimum requirements" for a function argument that will be passed.

I've got this code as an example

```
public function math(int $number) {
    if($number <= 0) {
        echo "Number cannot be less or equal to 0";
    }
}
```

Now what I would like to achieve is to cut that code a bit shorter

For example **(Non-working, dummy code)**

```
public function test(int $number = (($number <= 0) ? "" : $number)) {
    echo "Value of integer number is greater than 0";
}
```

This way I could just return a string or some other datatype to throw the error since the argument itself is set to be an integer, but unfortunately ternary operators cannot be used within function arguments itself.

Any recommendations what could I do regarding this?

I've tried googling for something similiar but couldn't find.

The only way I found the result way by using a separate class to process the argument and then return the error if needed..

```
public function test(MinCheck $number)
```

Then I could just do a quick check within the MinCheck constructor and finish it but that way I'm not really sure about its performance since call towards this function would be quite frequent

Comment: PHP doesn't support *guard clauses* or *pattern matching*, you'll have to do it the old fashioned way.

Comment: What's wrong with the first example? It's clear, concise, says what it does. I don't think there's any reason to refactor that.

Comment: If you're happy with the semantics of the second option, then performance shouldn't be a concern. There isn't a way to put validation logic in a function declaration in PHP (or in any other language I'm aware of), you'll just need to find a pattern you're happy with.

Comment: @iainn http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards :)

Comment: Alternatively you can use an exception https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php

Comment: @deceze Well *of course* it would be Erlang...

Comment: @iainn http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards :)

Comment: Hmm I like the option that @AmazingDreams poped up, seems decent enough for new way of doing it. There aint nothing bad with the old fashioned way, but for example as guards could be cool in PHP